# ImportError: No module named mime.base

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

Even though I am not using email related modules in my python Script. I keep on getting this error Saying ImportError: No module named mime.base on EMR. But I am good when running pySpark jobs

Comment: Can you post your code, please? 

At some point not your code, you are calling a module that was not imported or installed. We need more details, to help you.

Comment: I tried multiple scripts which are running fine in another EMR but there is something wrong with this specific EMR

Comment: Please, post traceback to our verify the error, because this error is very generic. You can use 

{code}
   try:
    except (Exception) as error:
        msg = error.message
        print("Exception in user code:")
        print('-' * 60)
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        print('-' * 60)
{code}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an IDE like atom or Notepad, press CTRL + F and enter `mime.base` this will find in all your projects where that module is called so you can remove it

Comment: I am running my scripts on EMR not in IDE